# ProgressDialog is not working

Tags: android, progressdialog

I would like to show a ProgresDialog but I don´t know what is wrong in my code. The ProgressDialog is not showing. Any idea please.

```
imageBtnRouteStart.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
      public void onClick(View v) { 
          dialog = ProgressDialog.show(_activity, "", "Loading...", true, false);

          new OtherActivity().SaveR(_id, _activity, true, true);


             //** Launch the activity
             Intent showContent = new Intent(_activity.getApplicationContext(),
                        NewActivity.class);
             _activity.startActivity(showContent);

      }
    });
```

Comment: Just curious. What do you want to achieve except showing the `ProgressDialog`?

Comment: First, show the dialog "Loading...", after call "SaveR" process and after that start a new activity

Comment: Base on your code, you start another activity after showing a dialog. That dialog is behind of started activity.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
ProgressDialog pDialog = new ProgressDialog(activity.this);
pDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
pDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
pDialog.setCancelable(true);
pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
pDialog.show();
```

But in your function you wanted the progress dialog to show and directly intent after that.
It most likely will show the progress dialog for less than a sec then intent will take place.